# $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and its dimension

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups

I want to prove that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ and find its dimension (as a real subgroup). Okay, let's consider the following action of $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ on $Mat_n(\mathbb{C})$:
$$(x, y) \longrightarrow xyx^{*}$$
If i take $y= 1$ I can see that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is its kernel, so it's a Lie subgroup. Is this proof correct?
To prove that its dimension is $2n^2$ (is it true?) I can look at the tangent space at $1 \in U_n(\mathbb{C})$. So I have that $T_1 U_n(\mathbb{C}) = \{A: A + A^* = 0\}$. But how from this I can find that its dimension is $2n^2$? Moreover, is there any calculation of dimension which calculates the codimension?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dimension of $SU(N)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515412/dimension-of-sun)

Comment: I don't think the dimension of $U_n$ is $2n^2$ as a real Lie group.  Since $U_n$ is the stabilizer of $1$ under the action you described, its dimension should be $2n^2$ minus the dimension of the orbit space $xx^{\ast} : x \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos no, there is no proof that it's subgroup and more there is no proof of equvialence for first answer, i am interested more in some less direct proof

Comment: Every closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie subgroup.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos but why it's closed?Because it's a preimage of $\{-1, +1\}$ of $det$ map from $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ to $\mathbb{C}^{*}$?

Comment: No. Because it is the preimage of $\{\operatorname{Id}_n\}$ with respect to the map $x\mapsto x^*x$.